# PageBlockSection Inputfield not displaying after deploy to partial sandbox

Tags: visualforce, deployment, sandbox

I've deployed a VisualForce page and its controller from my Dev sandbox to a Partial sandbox. In Dev it displayes my inputfield, but in Partial it doesn't. I checked in the debug log that the controller runs and the logs look identical in both sandboxes. 
What am I missing? I put some text before and after just to test...

Dev:

[image: Dev sandbox]

Partial:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you didn't include profile settings, your user may not have access to that field via field level security.

Comment: Thanks Christian - because the field was a new one, and the partial sandbox was refreshed from production where the new field doesn't exist, I didn't have access. I assumed as the admin I'd have access to everything. Silly me...